# Google Directory API - List all organizational units does not include the root organizational unit

Tags: python, google-workspace

I am trying to fetch organizational units in our Google Workspace.
Client: Python.

It works well, except it DOES not include the root organizational unit.

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)

try:
    results = service.orgunits().list(customerId='Our_Customer_Id', type='all').execute()
    org_units = results.get('organizationUnits', [])

    org_unit_dict = {}

    for org_unit in org_units:
        org_unit_dict[org_unit['orgUnitId']] = {
        'name': org_unit['name'],
        'parent_id': org_unit.get('parentOrgUnitId')
        }
```

The result missing the root OU which is "/".

We need this root OU.

I searched the web and read the API description but I had no clue.
I tried to pass the `orgUnitPath` argument to the list api passing '/' but the result still missing the root OU.